# HOME_ANDROID environment variable issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sdk

I know there are already several questions related to this error. I have tried them all (no kidding, that's all I've been doing for the past two days) and none of them have worked. The below error occurred when I was trying to create a new android project for ionic:

```
Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent 
path: /Home/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory`
```

I used `echo` in order find out where `ANDROID_HOME` was and it returned the exact location that the error returned. My theory is that the SDK cannot be placed here but that doesn't make much sense to me. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To set ANDROID_HOME permanently Right click on 
My Computer>Properties>Advanced System Settings>Environment variables

**1.** Add system variable

```
**name** = "ANDROID_HOME" 
**value** = "C:\(Location of Android SDK\Android-sdk)\android-sdk"
```

**2.** Above system varialbe you can see your PATH,

```
Edit PATH "%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools"
```

**and then save**

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I'm on ubuntu (not sure if that changes much) and I don't have a "my computer" I have a "computer" when I right click on it and go to properties though, I can't find Advanced system.

Comment: Which windows OS do you have ?

Comment: I'm running ubuntu

Comment: please refer this for set environment variable in Ubuntu..


https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables